# Java-trouble with not equal to

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a question. But the program control is going into the if statement even when both the numbers I check are the same which is not supposed to happen. What is the reason?

```
static int lonelyinteger(int[] a) {
Integer[] b=new Integer[a.length];
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    b[i]=new Integer(a[i]);
}
int val=0;
Arrays.sort(b);
boolean flag=false;
for(int i=0;i<a.length-2;i+=2)
    if (b[i]!=b[i+1]){
        val=b[i];
        flag=true;
        break;
    }
if(flag==true)
    return val;
else
    return b[a.length-1];
```

Comment: what is the content of `int[] a`?

Comment: Why are you using `Integer` instead of `int`?

Comment: @jesper I wanted to use the sort function. Since I can use descending sort only with objects, I tend to use Integer even when I don't require descending sort

Comment: @NoobEditor content is just any integer

Comment: There are specialized versions of `Arrays.sort()` that work on different kinds of arrays of primitive types, including one that works on `int[]`. No need to use an `Integer[]`.

Comment: @jesper can you please provide a link or syntax of that. I'm unable to find it.

Comment: The API docs for `java.util.Arrays`, here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `!=` on `Integer` objects. This will only work with integer values between `-128` and `127` ([reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching)) because these are cached by the JVM. But it won't work for larger/smaller values. Instead use `.equals`

```
if (!b[i].equals(b[i+1])){
     val=b[i];
     flag=true;
     break;
}
```

As correctly pointed out by Jesper in the comments, the cache used for `Integer` objects by the JVM is **not used** when you force the JVM to create new Integer objects through the explicit call of the constructor as in `new Integer(value)`. Calling the constructor will create new `Integer` instances instead of returning the cached `Integer` instances, which means that `!=` and `==` which check whether the two objects are the same instance will always think the instances are different.

Comment: And `!=` and `==` will return `false` even with values between `-128` and `127` here because he is creating new `Integer` objects explicitly with `new`.

Comment: @Jesper True. I didn't notice that the OP was using `new`. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

1) Do not use `new Integer()` use `Integer.valueOf()` instead.

2) Use `Object.equals()` when comparing objects.

```
if (b[i]!=b[i+1]) {
  ...
}
```

should be

```
if (!b[i].equals(b[i+1])) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: What is the reason behind using Integer.valueOf() rather than new Integer() ?

Comment: `new Integer()`always creates a new object whereas `Integer.valueOf()` can use predefined constants. This is applicable to all classes that support `valueOf()` (eg. BigDecimal, Long, Boolean etc.)

Comment: @alikox-What about auto-boxing here, why comparing using equals, wasn't == satisfying purpose in your case!

Comment: if the array b was created as `int[] b` instead of `Integer[] b` it would be OK. Autoboxing / unboxing wont work here, see [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html] for details.